# Ubuntu Dock doesn't work

Tags: 19.04, ubuntu-dock

After upgrading Ubuntu 19.04, Ubuntu Dock extension shows an error message as follows.

[image]

Before the upgrade, Ubuntu Dock worked well and showed no error.

When I click 'Error loading extension', I get this in Ubuntu software.

[image]

Note that I am asking about Ubuntu Dock, not Dash-to-Dock because it already works properly.

Comment: Please explain the "asking about Ubuntu Dock, not Dash-to-Dock because it already works properly" part with a bit more details. What happens if you disable Dash-to-Dock and reboot? Ubuntu Dock is a fork of Dash-to-Dock, it's highly recommended not to try to enable them both at the same time.

Comment: When I disable Dash-to-Dock extension and reboot, the original dock of Ubuntu will not show. And I cannot turn on Ubuntu Dock extension because of the error as shown above. I would like to have the original Ubuntu Dock back.

Comment: What happens if you reinstall it by running `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`?

Comment: It is still the same. Ubuntu-Dock extension still contains the error. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar issue to this one, though I never had installed Dash-to-Dock.

After upgrading an 18.10 Ubuntu installation to 19.04 on my GPD Pocket, my Dock never worked again.  I ended up having to reinstall instead of upgrade to fix it.  When I upgraded that install from 19.04 to 19.10, I did not have the same issue.

I just wrote the incident off as a fluke since I had not seen it happen on any other machine.

Good Luck!!